# Generic type implementing Generic interface syntax?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Say you have a scenario like the following:

```
public class MyVehicle<TType, TLoc> : IDrive<TType, TLoc> where TLoc: IVehicle, IMove<TType>
```

Do both `TLoc` parameters inherit from `IVehicle`? Additionally does one or both `TLoc` inherit from `IMove<TType>`?

If both `TLoc` parameters do not inherit from `IVehicle` how do I properly declare that?

**Question**: How do you distinguish between what `MyVehicle` is inheriting from and what `TLoc` is?

*(The context was made up on the spot in an attempt to reduce the complexity of my real usage. The syntax and functionality of the generic parameters is my focus)*

Comment: There is only one `TLoc` declared! The other occurrences refer back to the first "mention" of `TLoc` which is the declaration of `TLoc`. Try this to understand: `class MyVehicle<TLoc> : IDrive<TWhatLoc> { ... }`

Comment: And two type parameters cannot have the same name, of course, so this is illegal too: `class MyVehicle<TLoc, TLoc> { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do both `TLoc` parameters inherit from `IVehicle`?

There is only one `TLoc` parameter, it's just used in two places. Therefore, both the second type parameter of `MyVehicle` and the second type parameter of `IDrive` will derive from `IVehicle`, because both of them will refer to the same type. Same goes for inheriting from `IMove<TType>`.

> How do you distinguish between what `MyVehicle` is inheriting from and what `TLoc` is?

`MyVehicle` class implements a generic interface instantiated with two type parameters. `TLoc` happens to be one of these type parameters.

Comment: So if I wanted both `MyVehicle` and `TLoc` to implement `IVehicle` and `IMove<TType>` I would do `public class MyVehicle<TType, TLoc> : IVehicle, IMove<TType>, IDrive<TType, TLoc> where TLoc: IVehicle, IMove<TType>` correct? (I'm just trying to make sure I understand, which is most easily done for me via example. I'm not trying to be difficult :D)

Answer (score 1):

> Do both TLoc parameters inherit from IVehicle?

Technically, `TLoc` must be either a type that implements `IVehicle` or another interface that "inherits" from it.  But in the way I tihnk you mena "inherit" then yes; in fact they must be the same type.

> Additionally does one or both TLoc inherit from IMove?

Both, in your sense of the word "inherit".

> If both TLoc parameters do not inherit from IVehicle how do I properly declare that?

Well there is only one `TLoc` so I'm not sure what you mean.  You can't use a different generic parameter in the class and the interface it implements.

You could add an *additional* generic parameter to the class:

```
public class MyVehicle<TType, TLoc1, TLoc2> 
    : IDrive<TType, TLoc1> 
    where TLoc1: IVehicle, IMove<TType>
    where TLoc2: IVehicle, IMove<TType>
```

Then you *could* use different types for `TLoc1` and `TLoc2`.